# SaveChangesAsync en EF solo guarda la primera operación

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, wcf

Tengo un problema al insertar asincronamente, el panorama es el siguiente.

En un servicio WCF se recibe una petición se procesa, una vez procesado, se debe guardar el registro y actualizar un campo en especifico (un contador)

Entonces, tengo lo siguiente.

```
public async Task InsertarRegistroAsync(string[] Datos)
{
  //Varias Operaciones
  await _dbcontext.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

y

```
public async Task ActualizarContadorAsync(int UsuarioID)
{
  //Varias Operaciones
  await _dbcontext.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

En el flujo del consumo del servicio, llego a la siguiente parte.

```
WSTFDController.InsertarRegistroAsync(Datos);
WSTFDController.ActualizarContadorAsync(IDUsuario);
```

Y aquí el problema, solo se guarda/actualiza el primer Async que coloque, en este caso es Insertar, pero si pongo primero Consumir, actualiza y no inserta y viceversa, alguna idea?

Saludos.

Comment: ¿Estás llamando `InsertarRegistroAsync` con `await` también?

Comment: saludos @Archer_A, el flujo es secuencial, cierto? Es decir, primero se ejecuta InsertarRegistroAsync, y luego ConsumirTimbreAsync, verdad?

Comment: como es eso de actualiza y no inserta ? si pones el consumir primero estas recuperando mediante un query la entidad, pero no estas realizando ningun insert/update de la entidad

Comment: @fredyfx Si, primero se ejecuta InsertarRegistroAsync luego ConsumirTimbresAsync, pero sea el orden que ponga, ya sea primero insertar luego consumir, a nivel base de datos solo se ve reflejado el cambio del primero que se ejecuto.

Comment: @Equiso Ambos tienen await

Comment: @LeandroTuttini Me refería a lo siguiente si pongo este orden, WSTFDController.InsertarRegistroAsync(Datos);
WSTFDController.ActualizarContadorAsync(IDUsuario); primero inserta y la sig acción de actualizar no lo hace, si lo pongo al revés WSTFDController.ActualizarContadorAsync(IDUsuario); WSTFDController.InsertarRegistroAsync(Datos); actualiza pero no inserta

Comment: Hola @Archer_A. Lo primero seria saber tanto en un orden de ejecución como en otro si se produce alguna excepción por la cual no se ejecute la segunda operación al tenerla enmascarada u otra cosa. Sin saber cómo tienes implementado esos métodos no me es posible saberlo a ciencia cierta. Puedes activar una opción desde Visual Studio para que la ejecución de la depuración se detenga en la linea que provoca una excepción. (lo pongo en ingles ya que es el idioma de mi VS) Menu Debug/Windows/Execption Settings/ marcar las opciones de Common Language Runtime Exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Veo que tu contexto es una variable privada, el context es idisposable, te recomiendo que lo utilices con

```
using(var context = new DbContext()){ //acciones a db }
```

Quizás esto resuelva tu problema.

Un saludo.